# Reviving a stale mount

Tags: centos, mount, cifs

I have a mount point to a `cifs` share that goes stale sometimes.

```
# ls /mnt
ls: cannot access /mnt/code: Input/output error
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? code
```

In an attempt to revive this mount point I run `mount /mnt/code` or `mount -a` which brings me to my question. Why do I get the following error message?

```
# mount /mnt/code
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

# mount -a

# ls /mnt
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Apr  2 12:40 code
```

Running `mount /mnt/code` on CentOS returns the above error. Running the same from RHEL works fine.

Is there an universal way to revive a stale mount point?